# Click Sound for Checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, audio

I want a sound click when user check a box. I use Ubuntu Natty, Eclipse Indigo and my code is for Android 2.2. Compilation is ok, but no sound is played. I've looked for a simple coding in Google but only I found complex examples in this issue, wondering. Here's my code, what is wrong?

```
   package com.stufflist;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.CheckBox;

   public class ListStuff extends Activity {


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.liststuff);
   }

   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.liststuff, menu);
    return true;
   }

   public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    view.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.CheckBox07:
            if (checked)
                view.playSoundEffect(0);
                Log.v((String) view.getTag(),"yeah");
            break;
        case R.id.CheckBox06:
            if (checked)
                view.playSoundEffect(1);
                Log.v((String) view.getTag(),"yeah2");
            break;
        // TODO: Veggie sandwich
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure "Audible Selection" is enabled on your device...

Comment: yeah, it was already enabled. I just looked at my Logcat when I checked one of the box and there's an error message: system_process / Media Player / error(1 , -2147483648) and a TAG from AudioService warning. What the h*** means that? I'am a little fresh in Android and Java. But I realize that logcat message is involved in my problem.

Comment: Are you testing on the emulator?

Comment: @JoeCoolman Put the full StackTrace from your LogCat into your question.

Comment: @BrainCrash yes, I tested this in my emulator only.
I am not sure if I've installed Eclipse correctly, I've installed this manually, not via Ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 3):

OnClickListener is the only way to get the default touch feedback to solve this.. I had similar problem and solved it...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the majority of the "target version" API for the AVD you can create doesn't have built in Tones.

I tested on the API Level 15 that has some built-in Ringtones but it seems that the "FX_KEY_CLICK" and others are missing there too.

It is best if you can do this kind of tests on a real device.

Comment: Weird !. I tested it on my tablet and the checkboxes sound only when you check them fast, several times .